# Stop checkbox to be checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am studying JavaScript and test a function that I thought could prevent the checkbox from be checked ([code sample](http://jsbin.com/ihExoWo/1/edit)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var myBox = document.getElementById('bike');
myBox.addEventListener('click', stopCheck, false);

function stopCheck(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="bike" >I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

but the code does not work. Probably stopCheck is executed AFTER the checkbox changes the checked state. How to fix it?

Comment: maybe onmousedown instead of onclick ?

Comment: No harm in practicing, but in real life you'd just add a `disabled` attribute to the checkbox.

Comment: @Juhana if you don't want to make a user angry >:-} I am sure 95% of software developers indeed want to make a user angry...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript getElementByID() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829925/javascript-getelementbyid-not-working)

Comment: I try to understand events and the event bubbling, and the `preventDefault` function.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ihExoWo/3/

Comment: can't you just add the disabled attribute to the checkboxes?

Comment: By the way your code `does` work. Try your own fiddle

Comment: Nope I have not changed anything, I just took the link OP gave. Which is http://jsbin.com/ihExoWo/1/edit

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky You added the disabled properties. The JavaScript doesn't work in your example. (Sorry, commented on wrong jsbin first)

Comment: Your are overlooking the link I guess. Ignore my code and see the OP's fiddle url. It works for me there without any changes.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Well yes, it's not the same code as in the question.

Comment: Then that's something else, I would consider their own fiddle url to be an authoritative  replica of the code in question. Its the difference between the code there and here which brought about this confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be because when you use document.getElementById ,the Dom tree is not created fully yet.
move the script below may helps:

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="bike" >I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var myBox = document.getElementById('bike');
myBox.addEventListener('click', stopCheck, false);

function stopCheck(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Their code already works : http://jsbin.com/ihExoWo/2/edit  does what it intends to do

Comment: With that - document.getElementById('bike') - you'll just get one element.

Answer (score 2):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TQw6v/)

Your `script` is not able to find element.

Just move your script after form/before closing `body` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Use [document.getElementsByName](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-getelementsbyname) which returns an array of the elements with the names, in this case the checkboxes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
       var vehicle = document.getElementsByName("vehicle");

        for(var i=0;i<vehicle.length;i++){
            vehicle[i].onclick = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            };
        }



    };

</script>

<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="bike" >I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car
</form>
</body>
</html>
```