# document.getElementById does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

Firefox returns null when I try to call document.getElementById on an element.

Here is the call

```
document.getElementById('interaction4793')
```

However the element is present in the DOM. I can find it

```
<interaction id="interaction4793">
    <action id="action3268" trigger="enter" type="hover" />
    <reaction delay="0" id="reaction3709" options="reloadOnly" target="page0001" transition="none" type="showPage" />
</interaction>
```

Even when I select it from the inspector and use the [$0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) trick it returns null:

```
document.getElementById($0.id)
```

When I try to get the elements from getElementsById it works.

EDIT:
Chrome and Safari do not return null. I tested Firefox (version 26) on Window and MacOS both return null.

EDIT2:
I think Firefox do not understand that the attribute `id` is the id. When I search by attribute with jquery I can find the interaction:

```
console.log($('#interaction102').length); // returns 0
console.log($('[id="interaction102"]').length); // returns 1
```

Comment: *When* do you call `document.getElementById('interaction4793')`?

Comment: [Works for me with Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/BsNsk/)

Comment: Yes it's strange, it works for me too on a blank page. When I try it in my webapp, it returns always null...

Comment: I call it during the use of the webapp. The DOM is already ready and the element is there.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another tag with the same `id`?

Comment: Yes because `$('[id="interaction4793"]').length` returns 1

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered here: [JavaScript getElementByID() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829925/javascript-getelementbyid-not-working)

Sometimes happen when the content of your website is not already loaded and crash.

Hope to be helpful

EDIT1: You can also try this: **var yourvar= $("#interaction4793")[0];** It works for me

Comment: Actually jQuery returns an empty collection. But the element is loaded. With Firebug if I try `document.getElementById(document.getElementsByTagName('interaction')[0].id)` it returns null. It does not make any sense to me...