# Why is not this code working properly with getElementById?

Tags: alert, document, getelementbyid, console.log

Can anyone tell me
why this code for displaying
`document.getElementById("ibody").innerHTML=...` is not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var v=new Date();
    document.write("Avec document.write() = "+v);
    window.alert("Avec window.alert() = "+v);
    alert("Avec alert() = "+v);
    console.log("Avec console.log = "+v);
    document.getElementById("ibody").innerHTML=
        "Avec getElementById() ds DIV = "+v
</script>

<body id="ibody"></body>
```

Comment: formate your source code, and show us your html source code too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript getElementByID() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829925/javascript-getelementbyid-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Because at the point you are running the code, the `<body>` element does not exist.

Try wrapping the code block in an event handler that runs once the DOM finishes loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener(
        'DOMContentLoaded',
        function () {
            var v=new Date();
            document.write("Avec document.write() = "+v);
            window.alert("Avec window.alert() = "+v);
            alert("Avec alert() = "+v);
            console.log("Avec console.log = "+v);
            document.getElementById("ibody").innerHTML=
                "Avec getElementById() ds DIV = "+v
        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

keep the javascript code under the body decleared

Comment: <body id="ibody"></body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var v=new Date();
    document.write("Avec document.write() = "+v);
    window.alert("Avec window.alert() = "+v);
    alert("Avec alert() = "+v);
    console.log("Avec console.log = "+v);
    document.getElementById("ibody").innerHTML= "Avec getElementById() ds DIV = "+v
</script>

Comment: `<script>` elements are invalid outside of `<head>` or `<body>` elements. What you are suggesting is [invalid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html).

Comment: you can keep the <script></script> at the bottom of the page as well. and this the best practice to keep the js code at the bottom of the page, and <script> elements are never invalid outside of <head> or <body>

Comment: Of course they're invalid. As per my link above, the only elements allowed inside `<html>` are a single `<head>` followed by a single `<body>` (see Permitted content).

Comment: The link you have shared , that code is absolutely ok, If you declare a function for any event like click etc, then you can keep the function inside the head or anywhere else . But your piece of code has no event , so when it interpreted then the body is not yet interpreted , this is why throwing error, so I am suggesting to keep the js code at lest after the body element , because body need to render first then js code need to executed.