# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null at changeImage

Tags: javascript

I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null at changeImage function in the browser control.

But the slideshow is looks working fine. Dont know why this error msg is showing.
can anyone tell why is it happening.

My Code.

HTML:

```
<img src="images/1.jpg" alt="first Image" id="image" style="width:150px; height:150px;">    
<br/>

<input type="button" value="start the slide" onclick="startSlideShow()">    
<input type="button" value="end the slide" onclick="stopSlideShow()">
```

JS:

```
var interValId;
function startSlideShow() {
  setInterval(changeImage, 500);
}

function stopSlideShow() {
  clearInterval(interValId);
}

function changeImage() {
  var imageSource = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src");
  var currentImageNumber = imageSource.substring(imageSource.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, imageSource.lastIndexOf("/") + 2);

  if (currentImageNumber == 7) {
    currentImageNumber = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "images/" + (Number(currentImageNumber) + 1) + ".jpg");
}
```

Comment: My best guess is where you call the function changeImage. I.e, you all calling the function before the <img> tag appear, which results in document.getElementById returns nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829925/javascript-getelementbyid-not-working)

Comment: This code runs fine for me (except that the Stop button doesn't work because you're not setting `interValId`).

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what it says

```
(null).getAttribute("src")
```

therefore wherever you're calling `changeImage()` (you didn't demonstrate that in your question) there's no such element in the DOM, or the DOM was not ready to be manipulated.

- DOM not ready but `changeImage()` is called
- DOM is ready
- Interval now triggers another `changeImage()`
- Element is found
- Slider now works but you still have the previous error in console

---

A failsafe would be best:

```
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  if (!image) return; // failsafe

  // other code here

}
```

and always place your `<script>` right **before** the closing `</body>`  tag.

---

Additionally, for separation of concerns and better code architecture try to abandon inline `style` and `script`ing like `onclick` for a better alternative like `Element.addEventListener` right from your JS code:

```
var btnPlay = document.getElementById("play");
btnPlay.addEventListener("click", startSlideShow);
```

HTML:

```
<button id="play">PLAY</button>
```

Comment: Not necessary. Please check my answer.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yeah, great catch, but it still ignores the fact that DOM was not ready.

Comment: DOM doesn't have to be ready - with the fix, the functions _cannot_ be called until after the DOM is loaded.  I get where you are with this, but this isa simple problem. They'll be back to ask about "script tag before closing body" thing :-)

Comment: _"A failsafe would be best_": it would be better to understand and fix the problem, not hack around it.  This is not an issue about the DOM being ready, since the script doesn't run until the user presses the button.  There must be some other code that the OP isn't showing us.