# Laravel notification bell

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a question.

[image]

I have kind of this in my app. When I have 0 notifications, it becomes 0.

What I want is to delete the number, so it has only the bell (without number, and without that red background)

My code:

```
<a href="#" class="m-nav__link m-dropdown__toggle" id="m_topbar_notification_icon">
    <span class="m-nav__link-icon">
       <span class="m-nav__link-icon-wrapper">
          <i class="flaticon-music-2"></i>
       </span>
       <span class="m-nav__link-badge m-badge m-badge--success " id="notification">
       </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I am trying to do it with JavaScript:

```
<script>
  if(document.getElementById('notification').value() ===0)
  {
     document.getElementById('notification').style.display='none';
  }
</script>
```

Nothing happens. It still displays the bell with 0.

Comment: Do you have anything like react/angular/vue to work with?

Comment: @TarekAdam nope.

Comment: Can you confirm that your js is actually firing without error?  Is that <script> in the head or at the end of the page?  The reason I ask, is that 'notifications' may not exist yet if the script fires early.

Comment: @TarekAdam In the end

Comment: @TarekAdam has a point. See this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829925/javascript-getelementbyid-not-working

Comment: Do you need javascript for this? You can use css _pseudo class_ [empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) - `.notification:empty{display: none};` - assuming `#notification` is the element that contains the number.

Comment: your span has no "value()" method. and value property too. it is not an input. but you can use, for example, "innerText" property to get your notifications count

Answer (score 1):

I know your question uses Javsacript but as a simpler alternative, you *could* do this with the css *pseudo class* [empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty). However, you'd have to not output the number at all if it was 0.

```css
.notification{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.notification:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="badge">
  <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
  <span class="notification">4</span>
</div>

<div class="badge">
  <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
  <span class="notification"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .value(), try using .innerHTML to check if notifications === 0. .innerHTML gets or sets the HTML or XML contained within the element while .value() gets the value property of the element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

```
if(document.getElementById('notification').innerHTML === '0')
{
  document.getElementById('notification').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Since you are using Laravel, I suggest you use the blade @if statement https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#if-statements

```
@if(notifications > 0)
  <span class="m-nav__link-badge m-badge m-badge--success " id="notification">{{ notifications }}</span>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using blade? If so put a check around the element.

```
@if(notifications > 0)
  this will only be displayed if there are greater notifications than 0
@endif
```

If you really want to use js, try to comment above this one